# arrayList of Strings contain specific characters java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, character

Trying to a java school PigLatin project where I loop through an Arraylist of Strings and check to see if the String at char 0 has a vowel. Is there a easier way than writing out || for each vowel(lowercase and uppercase). Here's an example of me beginning to list it out the long way...

```
    for (int i = 0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
        if (arrayList.get(i).charAt(0) == 'a' || arrayList.get(i).charAt(0) == 'e'){
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i) + "way");
        }

    }
```

I can't find a straightforward answer to this online. I've seen stringbuilder and other potential complex options but not sure if I need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static method `isVowel(char c)` to use in your conditional statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
    if (isVowel(arrayList.get(i).charAt(0))) {
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(i) + "way");
    }
}

public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
  return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch case if it helps you feel any better or use ASCII codes rather.

Define a function isVowel or something similar, working on the same logic, for yourself and reuse it whenever you need.

But IMHO, at the very fundamental level you must work it individually for all vowels you gotta check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pattern matching](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to slightly reduce clutter. As was already mentioned, you can also add `isVowel()` method to separate the vowel checking logic.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class PigLatin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
                "apricot",
                "banana",
                "lemon",
                "orange",
                "Input",
                "Test",
                "User"
        );

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            String word = words.get(i);

            if (startsWithVowel(word)) {
                System.out.println(word + "way");
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean startsWithVowel(String word) {
        return word.matches("^[AEIOUaeiou].*$");
    }
}
```

You can replace the indexed for loop with the [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
    for (String word : words) {
        if (startsWithVowel(word)) {
            System.out.println(word + "way");
        }
    }
```

Here's a [functional way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), which is more concise, if you are interested:

```
    words.stream()
         .filter(word -> startsWithVowel(word))
         .forEach(word -> System.out.println(word + "way"));
```

Prints:

```
apricotway
orangeway
Inputway
Userway
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code snippet to give you a shorter way :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings={"Aello","Bello","iello","Oello","Zello"};
    List<String> al=Arrays.asList(strings); //creating a list with entities....Replace it with your ArrayList...
    String vowelsString="aeiouAEIOU"; 
    for(String s:al){  //for each String in List
        if(vowelsString.contains(s.charAt(0)+"")) //charAt(0) represents the beginning of string
            System.out.println(s+" way");
    }
```